# how to fix this cannot resovle this symbol?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android and i have been learning android form udacity.
in one of their lesson they asked students to copy code from git hub , i did so but when I pasted the code an error popped saying cannot symbol number format.please help me to resolve this and please give answer in detail it's a request. thank you.
..........................................................................................................................................................
 link of github :- https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fa134c55a4a43e8d6004

...............................................................................java code which i've written:-

```js
package com.example.android.justjava;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.;

/**
     * This app displays an order form to order coffee.
     */
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        /**
         * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
         */
        public void submitOrder(View view) {
            display(18 * 3 + 4 / (2+2) -1);
            displayPrice(2*5);
        }

        /**
         * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
         */
        private void display(int number) {
            TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
            quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
        }
       /**
         * This method displays the given price on the screen.
         */
        private void displayPrice(int number) {
            TextView priceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_text_view);
            priceTextView.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number));
        }
    }
```

.............................................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add `import java.text.NumberFormat;`

In such way build system imports class you required.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html) describes it in details

Comment: @SunayKundalwal, you try to use functionality from package differs from your own one. It's impossible for build system to know what class exactly you want to use and so you should either import in in top of the file or specify in code explicitly (`java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()...`).